# css link hover and javascript not working when page contains asp.net ajax updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a master page with a menu that rely on a css template and a little javascript for small screens. The menu works really nice for child pages that does not contain an UpdatePanel. But when the page contains an UpdatePanel the menu stops work. My a:hover css is not working and the javascript draw the a button but clicking it have no effect on html. Some basic css is working but seems like the interactive css linke link events and such is broken. This happen direct on laod of the page. I have not even clicked anything inside tha updatepanel

Any suggestion on what might be wrong here?

Comment: check for javascript errors.

Comment: I find no errors in the log for javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out to be the wrong path to one of my javascript files :P